# Show how many rows data has moved in relation to adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of text entries in columns `A` and `B`.

[image]

In column `C` I would like to show how many rows an entry of column `B` differs in relation to its row in column `A`.

The row differences can be positive or negative (i.e the data can move up or down rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a list in column A, and your new list in column B, in CELL C1 you could apply the below formula, and drag down.

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)-ROW(A1),"")
```

[image]

Positive numbers indicate rows moved down, negative up. To reverse this use :

```
=IFERROR(ROW(A1)-MATCH(A1,B:B,0),"")
```

**Edit. As per comments**

See new formula as asked for.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)-ROW(A1)=0,"Did Not Move","Moved "&MATCH(A1,B:B,0)-ROW(A1)&" Rows "&IF(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)-ROW(A1)<0,"Down",IF(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)-ROW(A1)>0,"Up",""))),"Not Found In Column A")
```

Comment: Thank you Peter @PeterH, I have edited my question to give more clarification to what I am seeking to achive

Comment: @GovVek see update